# Sending set of string in HTTP query string

Tags: data-structures, sets

I'd like to implement pagination for an API. The elements are ordered by time but there can be multiple elements with the same timestamp. So there can be some duplication between the last elements of the previous page and the first elements of the next pages.

So far the de-duplication is handled on the client side by keeping a set of the elements and checking for duplicates. I'd like to send this set in the HTTP request so that the backend can de-duplicate the entries before sending.

So I'm looking for a data structure that can be serialized to a string and be embedded as a query parameter.

Comment: I bet your elements, when stored in a database, have some kind of primary key `id`. You can use it to avoid duplicates by `order by timestamp, id` (and, of course, combine it with whatever approach you use for pagination).

Comment: Unfortunately not. The API is from a database. There is no I’d yet at least.